# SAS Append error

Tags: append, sas, proc

I am trying to append a dataset with different variables to base dataset with FORCE option. However everytime the loop iterates, it adds observations but is not adding the variable from the new dataset.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant part of your code? (i see you mention a loop as well) A few lines of data, enough to replicate the issue as well. Because right now it seems way too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC APPEND, even with FORCE options does not add VARIABLES, just RECORDS (observations). FORCE enables append if source table does not contain some of variables in target table, but does not add variables from source table if they do not exist in target.

Comment: This is true, conditionally on the base dataset existing - it will append new variables if the initial dataset does not exist.